APD active quenching circuit - please help to understand function
I'm trying to understand the circuit demonstrated in this publication - this is an active quenching circuit for an APD detector. Here is an image of the circuit in question:

Some information of components not mentioned in the above image, but presented in the publication:

As comparator a AD8611 was used
In another publication the author used a 74HC D-Flipflop, hence most likely the DFF1 should use the same component.

I have simulated the circuit in LTSpice and do have some more general questions - hope someone with a better understanding of circuit design and experience can help me with some of my questions.

The circuit does not specify some components:


DLY1 and DLY2 are delay elements. But these are not specified. What elements/components would these be? The element DLY1 has a specified delay time of approx. 6ns. Would it be reasonable to use RC components for the delay elements?
The NPN transistor Q1 was not specified. Would it be reasonable to use a MMBT3904?

I do understand (at least I hope so) the overall concept of the circuit:
a) Comparator gives a logic high when the APD detector has detected light (+Input of COMP goes above the level of -Input, generating a high signal at the output)
b) ~Q Output of the comparator drives the transistor to quench the APD.
c) (The publication specifies) that at point A voltage jump of 25V, a square signals with a width of 10ns and a rise and fall time of 1ns. Here are some of my problems understanding the circuit are. I can not see when simulating the circuit that at point A a voltage jump of ~25V can be seen.
.
Thanks a lot.

Your quench source isn't representative, to start. There is a dark current, which at -10 C and a reasonable over-voltage looks about like 100 nA from figure 3. A single photon doesn't have "watts" but only "joules". However, this causes a cascade/avalanche. I'm not going to attempt to spend the time needed to work out how this circuit interacts with that avalanche in order to figure out the peak pulse current in the APD. The authors are Ph.D.s specializing in this area and have spent years with this device, as well. So their notebook is full of that info. Your source doesn't cut it, though.

I also imagine that there are parasitics that the authors carefully and experimentally determined in constructing their custom unit. Their actual wired system will have a number of parasitics that they've annotated in their notebooks. They've provided you a behavioral picture. Their reality will be very much more nuanced. You should contact the authors, I think. If you are serious about this. The SAP500 datasheet provides a starting approach not too dissimilar to this one, hinting towards improvements that these authors have pursued. Give them a call/note/email.
